# Spring test - @ContextConfiguration exclude base class context

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

When testing with spring and @ContextConfiguration
Is there an option to exclude some of the base class contexts?
for example

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"context1.xml", "context2.xml"})
public class Base{
```

and extending class

```
public class someClass extends Base{
```

now I want someClass to use context1.xml but NOT context2.xml. is there a way to exclude it?
the issue is: I have a base class for all my tests (300 tests). I want **all** of them to use context1 which is a mock context that overrides the original one. Only **one** class should use the original context in order to test it (if the Base will not have it in its locations{} it will use the original).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, excluding contexts will not be possible.

However, I would advise you to take a look at the new [Spring 3 bean profiles](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html).

By specifying / activating the correct profiles you should be able to achieve the same thing in a cleaner way...

A nice article on unit / integration testing with spring bean profiles can be found [here](http://dontpanic.42.nl/2011/07/advanced-unit-testing-with-your-spring.html).